# Stripe; how to get subscriptionId when creating a customer with a new subscription

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I'm creating a new customer and adding them to a subscription in one call like so:

```
StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(StripeData.ApiKey);
var customerService = new CustomerService();
var myCustomer = new CustomerCreateOptions
    {
         Email = stripeEmail,
         Source = stripeToken,
         Plan = StripeData.MonthlySubscriptionPlanId
     };
Customer stripeCustomer = customerService.Create(myCustomer);
```

Then I used to be able to do this:

```
myLocalUser.StripeCustomerId = stripeCustomer.Id;
myLocalUser.StripeSubscriptionId = stripeCustomer.Subscriptions.Data[0]?.Id;
```

But now the API isn't returning the customer's subscriptions so the second line fails

Answer (score 0):

I'm now having to call the API again with this ugly code to get the customer's subscriptionId:

```
                    if (stripeCustomer.Subscriptions != null)
                    {
                        user.StripeSubscriptionId = stripeCustomer.Subscriptions.Data[0]?.Id;
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //get subscriptionId
                        var cust = customerService.Get(stripeCustomer.Id, new CustomerGetOptions
                        {
                            Expand = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { "subscriptions" }
                        });
                        if (cust.Subscriptions.Any())
                        {
                            stripeSubscriptionId = cust.Subscriptions.First().Id;
                        }
                    }
```

CustomerService.Create() doesn't have the same Expand parameter option that the Get() method does...

Answer (score 0):

This is expected, as subscriptions are [no longer included by default](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-subscriptions) on a customer object unless you expand them since [API version 2020-08-27](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2020-08-27).

Creating a customer with a source and plan is still possible (although not the recommended integration path anymore since you might run into problems with 3DS and tax rates), although since you are on a newer API version you won't get the `subscriptions` list back. If you can you should update to creating subscriptions [via their own API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create).

If you however still want to use this old integration path, you can still get the subscriptions back in the customer create call, you just need to expand the subscriptions on creation:

```
var customerService = new CustomerService();
var myCustomer = new CustomerCreateOptions
{
  Email = stripeEmail,
  Source = stripeToken,
  Plan = StripeData.MonthlySubscriptionPlanId
};
myCustomer.AddExpand("subscriptions");
Customer stripeCustomer = customerService.Create(myCustomer);
```